# 2D graph rendering algorithm supporting dynamically adding/removing nodes/edges

Tags: graphics, graph-theory

I've spent hours searching for an answer to this, but in most cases either the
question is about plots/charts (rather than graphs as in "control flow graph"),
or the answer "just use graphviz" is a valid answer.

However I have some constraints and requirements that make "just use graphviz" a
non-answer.

- The full graph is large enough that it's not possible to generate a graphviz
  for all of it.
- Nodes and edges will be dynamically added and removed.
- Nodes have lots of information that will be hidden by default and will be
  expanded on request (imagine every node as a table with expandable rows/cols)
- I want to be able to show only a subset of the graph on request, e.g. for
  features like "only show reachable part of the graph from this node" or "show
  all simple paths from this node to this node".

Basically I want to be able to start drawing nodes and edges on a 2D plane, and
add new nodes and edges dynamically. It's fine if nodes/edges move around as new
stuff is added. While I don't yet have hard requirements for this, it'd be good
if it looked "nice" -- for example if a node has lots of incoming edges (this is
a directed graph) ideally it'd be in a central place on the plane with all other
nodes around it etc.

Anything that gets me going would be helpful. Thanks.

(I don't know what label to add to this, adding "graph-theory" because I don't know what else to add)